How to play AES/CTR/NoPadding encrypted video onfly using AesCipherDataSource
I am using exoplayers latest version androidx.media3.exoplayer.I have a AES/CTR/NoPadding encrypted video online,i want to decrypt it and play using AesCipherDataSource.i dont want full decrypt and play,i want to decrypt onfly. i am using  AES 128.
i looked at these.
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/11306#issuecomment-1753321802
https://github.com/moagrius/EncryptedExoPlayerDemo/tree/master

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
